# Can I overwrite custom taxonomy FROM "public" TO "false"

Tags: customization, custom-taxonomy, archives

I have custom taxonomy within my WordPress installation that I created with a WordPress Plugin called Pods.

For various reasons, I need to set the registering of the loop from "public" to "false" to prevent post looping.

So, can anyone please point me in the right direction to do this?

My Custom Taxonomy is called "Countries" and it lists Countries!

Thanks, all pointers appreciated so that I can figure this one out.

I understand that to register custom taxonomy w/out a plugin you could so something like this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_tax' );

function create_book_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'genre',
        'book',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Genre' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
?>
```

So I guess my question is: is there a way to **overwrite** the settings from "public" to "false' whilst keeping the URL integrity?

What I am trying to achieve is to keep the public URL but remove the loop from my Custom Taxonomy.

I hope that makes sense

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you need help with. You just set `public` to `false`, as you've described. Do you just need to know how to register a taxonomy? It's thoroughly documented, so have you looked at that?

Comment: Yes you are right @JacobPeattie let me rewrite my question, thanks for the headsup

Comment: Keeping the URL but removing the loop doesn't make much sense to me. What's your ultimate goal? What should be at these URLs?

Comment: Thanks for helping @JacobPeattie so the reason is that I list events within that Custom taxonomy, - in this example by country. The issue is that there are hundreds of events and the pagination has gotten out of control....to alleviate this I'm thinking of removing the pagination and then simply adding "hand-picked" events - make sense? I am creating more trouble with this approach?

Comment: Really, I dont seem much value in reams and reams of pages that aren't really adding value....it's an unusual setup but I think it would tidy things up for my site (these are Custom Taxonomies, I'd keep WordPress "generic" Taxonomy as is)